# On a set inclusion in the proof that if a function $f(x)$ has some properties then it's a probability distribution function.

Tags: probability-theory

I am following *Probability Essentials* By Jean Jacod and Philip Protter where I reached the theorem I will post below. To answer the question I will make there is no need to read all the theorem since I am dubious about a simple set inclusion, the whole theorem is included for completeness and for the curious.

[image]

[image]

I do not understand when It says that $B_n \subset A_n$ Since it is possible for there to be a point $x$ in $B_1$ s-t. $x \notin A_2$ given the arbitrary nature of the sequence of sets $A_n$. Am I mistaken? If yes why? If no how could I salvage the proof?